# How to make SQL statement faster with Max function

Tags: sql

I have this query that works but it is very slow and it locks everyone out of the DB until it resolves is there anyway I can speed this up?

```
SELECT Item.Barcode,
  Hetype.Description,
  Max(StockTakeDetails.xStockTake),
  Max(OpScans.ScanDate) AS Max_ScanDate
FROM Item
  INNER JOIN Hetype ON Item.Type = Hetype.Type
  LEFT JOIN StockTakeDetails ON StockTakeDetails.xItemID = Item.Itemref
  LEFT JOIN OpScans ON Item.Itemref = OpScans.xItemRef
WHERE Item.Lastservice = 1 AND
  Item.Deleted = FALSE AND
  Item.CommissionStatus <> 4
GROUP BY Item.Barcode,
  Hetype.Description
```

Comment: I Think that the main question here is do you want to lock everyone? You can change the transaction isolation level if you are using a transaction. It might read dirty data but depending on your needs it may be a life saving. Also how large is the db?

Comment: SQL performance tuning requires more details. We don't even know what rdbms you are working with....

Comment: What is the database? It sounds like SQL Server--that would be important to note.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using SQL Server. If not, then this answer will not apply.

The problem is that you currently have a situation where a reader is blocking a writer. In order to prevent this, your database should be configured with *multiversioning* enabled.

This can be achieve in SQL Server by turning on Read Committed Snapshot Isolation.

Here's a good writeup on this process: [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)

Oracle databases have had multiversioning for decades (readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers), so it is common for Oracle developers to just assume it works the same in all databases, but this is not the case.
Nevertheless, SQL Server does support this feature, but it's not on by default.

Finally, there is a very rough SQL Server hack that you can use in a pinch: add the `NOLOCK` hint to your query. This is not a good idea as a long term solution, and can result in dirty reads. Nevertheless, if your query is for a summary web page that isn't used for reporting, it might be a reasonable candidate for this cheap and cheerful hack.
Read Committed Snapshot Isolation is the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have provided little information to help with optimization.  Your question doesn't have a database tag.  It doesn't have size information about the tables, or execution plans.

But, you appear to be joining a single table to two different tables, producing a Cartesian product.  This is probably the root of the performance. problem, so I would suggest rewriting the query using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT i.Barcode, ht.Description,
       (SELECT MAX(std.xStockTake),
        FROM StockTakeDetails std
        WHERE std.xItemID = i.Itemref
       ),
       (SELECT MAX(os.ScanDate)
        FROM OpScans os
        WHERE os.xItemRef = i.Itemref
       ) AS Max_ScanDate
FROM Item i JOIN
     Hetype ht
     ON i.Type = ht.Type
WHERE i.Lastservice = 1 AND
      i.Deleted = FALSE AND
      i.CommissionStatus <> 4
GROUP BY i.Barcode, ht.Description ;
```

Then for this query, you want the following indexes:

- `Item(LastService, Deleted, CommissionStatus, Itemref)`
- `HeType(Type, Description)`
- `StockTakeDetails(xItemID, xStockTake)`
- `OpScans(xItemID, ScanDate)`

There might be other improvements as well, but I suspect that this will solve your performance problems.